# How to enable MPMediaItemArtwork Next / Previous button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

I am using `AVAudioPlayer` in my project.
When application go in background or lock the device application play song using `AVAudioPlayer`.

My problem is that when i am download 2 song and play song using `AVAudioPlayer` and lock the device, song will be played but next and previous button is disabled.

I try enable button using bellow code :

```
[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].previousTrackCommand.enabled = YES;
[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].nextTrackCommand.enabled = YES;
```

And Also set Bellow code :

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

And set `MPMediaItemArtwork` detail Like This :

```
MPMediaItemArtwork *albumArt = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]];
[songInfo setObject:@"song title" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
[songInfo setObject:albumArt forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];
```

I also enable `BackgroundMode` From App Capability :

[image]

[image]

**Note : When i kill the app and run again, and play song and lock the device, next and previous button enable and work, but not work in first time.**

Then my question is why not enable Next/Previous button for first time ?

Thank in Advance.

Comment: I don't know about functionality but, http://pulkitgoyal.in/ios-music-player-on-the-lock-screen/ Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks buddy for your replay @AshishKakkad I have already do this step but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Can you target for previous and next track objects as below

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];

commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.enabled = YES;
commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.enabled = YES;

[commandCenter.nextTrackCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
    NSLog(@"Next Track");
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}];

[commandCenter.previousTrackCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
    NSLog(@"Previous Track");
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

//OR

```
[commandCenter.nextTrackCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(play)];

[commandCenter.previousTrackCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(play)];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

Your code looks fine...!

Comment: thanks for making this answer. but i already done this issue.using same code

Answer (score 1):

This is a working solution,
Latest Swift ios code

```
UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
        MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = false
        MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = false
        MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().playCommand.addTarget {event in
            
         //   self.playerPlay()
              return .success
            }
            MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().pauseCommand.addTarget {event in
                
          //      self.playerPause()
                
              return .success
            }
            MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().nextTrackCommand.addTarget {event in
              return .success
            }
            MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().previousTrackCommand.addTarget {event in
              return .success
            }
        
        var nowPlayingInfo = [String: Any]()
// prepare title
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = currentTrackTitle ?? "Buffering..."
// prepare Live stream
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyIsLiveStream] = true
        
// To set a Image
        let img = UIImage(named: "place_holder")
        let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork.init(boundsSize: img!.size, requestHandler: { (size) -> UIImage in
            return img!
            })
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = artwork
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way in Objective-C:

```
if(@available(iOS 11, *)) {
    MPRemoteCommandCenter* commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
    [commandCenter.playCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
    }];

    [commandCenter.pauseCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
    }];
    
    [commandCenter.nextTrackCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
    }];
    
    [commandCenter.previousTrackCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
    }];
}
```